# is it possible to exceed limit of bandwidth when using multi-core?

Tags: multithreading, cpu, benchmarking, bandwidth, numa

i'm testing bandwidth using fio benchmark tool.
here is my hardware spec

1. 2 socket per 10cores
2. Kernel version : 4.8.17
3. intel SSD 750 series

cpu : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2650 v3 @ 2.3GHZ , ssd : Intel Solid State Drive 750 series, 400GB, 20nm Intel NAND Flash Memory MLC. NVMe PCIe 3.0*4 ADD-In card.

I could invalidate the buffer/page cache parts of the files to be used prior to starting I/O when i made the fio file.

And i used O_DIRECT flag(non-buffered IO) to bypass the page cache and used linux native asynchronous I/O request.

when i test with one core, fio output says that 
bandwidth which core0 received is 1516.7MB/s.

it doesnt exceed bandwidth limitation of intel SSD 750. it doesn't matter.

here is test1 code.

```
[global]
filename=/dev/nvme0n1
runtime=10
bs=4k
ioengine=libaio
direct=1
iodepth=64
invalidate=1 
randrepeat=0
log_avg_msec=1000
time_based
thread=1
size=256m


[job1]
cpus_allowed=0
rw=randread
```

but, when i do this with 3cores, the total bandwidth of cores is exceeds
intel SSD 750 bandwidth limitation.

total amount of bandwidth of 3cores is about 3000MB/s.

according to intel SSD 750 spec, my intel SSD bandwidth limitation is 2200MB/s.

here is code of test2(3 cores)

```
[global]
filename=/dev/nvme0n1
runtime=10
bs=4k
ioengine=libaio
direct=1
iodepth=64

invalidate=1 
randrepeat=0
log_avg_msec=1000
time_based
thread=1
size=256m


[job1]
cpus_allowed=0
rw=randread

[job2]
cpus_allowed=1
rw=randread

[job3]
cpus_allowed=2
rw=randread
```

i don't know how this is happened.

---

**here is fio test output of test1**

```
job1: (g=0): rw=randread, bs=4K-4K/4K-4K/4K-4K, ioengine=libaio, iodepth=64
fio-2.2.10
Starting 1 thread

job1: (groupid=0, jobs=1): err= 0: pid=6924: Mon Jan 29 20:14:33 2018
  read : io=15139MB, bw=1513.8MB/s, iops=387516, runt= 10001msec
    slat (usec): min=0, max=42, avg= 1.97, stdev= 1.12
    clat (usec): min=5, max=1072, avg=162.70, stdev=20.17
     lat (usec): min=6, max=1073, avg=164.74, stdev=20.39
    clat percentiles (usec):
     |  1.00th=[  141],  5.00th=[  145], 10.00th=[  149], 20.00th=[  151],
     | 30.00th=[  155], 40.00th=[  157], 50.00th=[  159], 60.00th=[  161],
     | 70.00th=[  165], 80.00th=[  169], 90.00th=[  179], 95.00th=[  211],
     | 99.00th=[  229], 99.50th=[  262], 99.90th=[  318], 99.95th=[  318],
     | 99.99th=[  334]
    lat (usec) : 10=0.01%, 20=0.01%, 50=0.02%, 100=0.03%, 250=99.35%
    lat (usec) : 500=0.60%, 1000=0.01%
    lat (msec) : 2=0.01%
  cpu          : usr=22.32%, sys=77.64%, ctx=102, majf=0, minf=421
  IO depths    : 1=0.1%, 2=0.1%, 4=0.1%, 8=0.1%, 16=0.1%, 32=0.1%, >=64=99.9%
     submit    : 0=0.0%, 4=100.0%, 8=0.0%, 16=0.0%, 32=0.0%, 64=0.0%, >=64=0.0%
     complete  : 0=0.0%, 4=100.0%, 8=0.0%, 16=0.0%, 32=0.0%, 64=0.1%, >=64=0.0%
     issued    : total=r=3875556/w=0/d=0, short=r=0/w=0/d=0, drop=r=0/w=0/d=0
     latency   : target=0, window=0, percentile=100.00%, depth=64

Run status group 0 (all jobs):
   READ: io=15139MB, aggrb=1513.8MB/s, minb=1513.8MB/s, maxb=1513.8MB/s, mint=10001msec, maxt=10001msec

Disk stats (read/write):
  nvme0n1: ios=3834624/0, merge=0/0, ticks=25164/0, in_queue=25184, util=99.61%
```

---

**here is fio output of test2(3cores)**

```
job1: (g=0): rw=randread, bs=4K-4K/4K-4K/4K-4K, ioengine=libaio, iodepth=64

job2: (g=0): rw=randread, bs=4K-4K/4K-4K/4K-4K, ioengine=libaio, iodepth=64

job3: (g=0): rw=randread, bs=4K-4K/4K-4K/4K-4K, ioengine=libaio, iodepth=64

fio-2.2.10
Starting 3 threads

job1: (groupid=0, jobs=1): err= 0: pid=6968: Mon Jan 29 20:14:53 2018
  read : io=10212MB, bw=1021.2MB/s, iops=261413, runt= 10001msec
    slat (usec): min=1, max=140, avg= 2.49, stdev= 1.23
    clat (usec): min=4, max=970, avg=241.78, stdev=138.10
     lat (usec): min=7, max=972, avg=244.35, stdev=138.09
    clat percentiles (usec):
     |  1.00th=[   17],  5.00th=[   25], 10.00th=[   33], 20.00th=[   64],
     | 30.00th=[  135], 40.00th=[  225], 50.00th=[  306], 60.00th=[  330],
     | 70.00th=[  346], 80.00th=[  366], 90.00th=[  390], 95.00th=[  410],
     | 99.00th=[  438], 99.50th=[  446], 99.90th=[  474], 99.95th=[  502],
     | 99.99th=[  668]
    lat (usec) : 10=0.01%, 20=2.03%, 50=14.39%, 100=9.67%, 250=16.14%
    lat (usec) : 500=57.71%, 750=0.05%, 1000=0.01%
  cpu          : usr=17.32%, sys=71.84%, ctx=182182, majf=0, minf=318
  IO depths    : 1=0.1%, 2=0.1%, 4=0.1%, 8=0.1%, 16=0.1%, 32=0.1%, >=64=99.9%
     submit    : 0=0.0%, 4=100.0%, 8=0.0%, 16=0.0%, 32=0.0%, 64=0.0%, >=64=0.0%
     complete  : 0=0.0%, 4=100.0%, 8=0.0%, 16=0.0%, 32=0.0%, 64=0.1%, >=64=0.0%
     issued    : total=r=2614396/w=0/d=0, short=r=0/w=0/d=0, drop=r=0/w=0/d=0
     latency   : target=0, window=0, percentile=100.00%, depth=64
job2: (groupid=0, jobs=1): err= 0: pid=6969: Mon Jan 29 20:14:53 2018
  read : io=10540MB, bw=1053.1MB/s, iops=269802, runt= 10001msec
    slat (usec): min=1, max=35, avg= 1.93, stdev= 0.97
    clat (usec): min=5, max=903, avg=234.55, stdev=139.14
     lat (usec): min=7, max=904, avg=236.56, stdev=139.13
    clat percentiles (usec):
     |  1.00th=[   16],  5.00th=[   22], 10.00th=[   30], 20.00th=[   57],
     | 30.00th=[  112], 40.00th=[  207], 50.00th=[  298], 60.00th=[  330],
     | 70.00th=[  346], 80.00th=[  362], 90.00th=[  386], 95.00th=[  402],
     | 99.00th=[  426], 99.50th=[  438], 99.90th=[  462], 99.95th=[  494],
     | 99.99th=[  628]
    lat (usec) : 10=0.01%, 20=3.22%, 50=14.51%, 100=10.76%, 250=15.48%
    lat (usec) : 500=55.97%, 750=0.05%, 1000=0.01%
  cpu          : usr=26.08%, sys=59.08%, ctx=377522, majf=0, minf=326
  IO depths    : 1=0.1%, 2=0.1%, 4=0.1%, 8=0.1%, 16=0.1%, 32=0.1%, >=64=99.9%
     submit    : 0=0.0%, 4=100.0%, 8=0.0%, 16=0.0%, 32=0.0%, 64=0.0%, >=64=0.0%
     complete  : 0=0.0%, 4=100.0%, 8=0.0%, 16=0.0%, 32=0.0%, 64=0.1%, >=64=0.0%
     issued    : total=r=2698293/w=0/d=0, short=r=0/w=0/d=0, drop=r=0/w=0/d=0
     latency   : target=0, window=0, percentile=100.00%, depth=64
job3: (groupid=0, jobs=1): err= 0: pid=6970: Mon Jan 29 20:14:53 2018
  read : io=10368MB, bw=1036.8MB/s, iops=265406, runt= 10001msec
    slat (usec): min=1, max=102, avg= 2.48, stdev= 1.24
    clat (usec): min=5, max=874, avg=238.10, stdev=139.10
     lat (usec): min=7, max=877, avg=240.66, stdev=139.09
    clat percentiles (usec):
     |  1.00th=[   18],  5.00th=[   27], 10.00th=[   39], 20.00th=[   72],
     | 30.00th=[  113], 40.00th=[  193], 50.00th=[  290], 60.00th=[  330],
     | 70.00th=[  350], 80.00th=[  370], 90.00th=[  398], 95.00th=[  414],
     | 99.00th=[  442], 99.50th=[  454], 99.90th=[  474], 99.95th=[  498],
     | 99.99th=[  628]
    lat (usec) : 10=0.01%, 20=1.51%, 50=12.00%, 100=13.78%, 250=17.81%
    lat (usec) : 500=54.84%, 750=0.05%, 1000=0.01%
  cpu          : usr=17.96%, sys=71.88%, ctx=170809, majf=0, minf=319
  IO depths    : 1=0.1%, 2=0.1%, 4=0.1%, 8=0.1%, 16=0.1%, 32=0.1%, >=64=99.9%
    submit    : 0=0.0%, 4=100.0%, 8=0.0%, 16=0.0%, 32=0.0%, 64=0.0%, >=64=0.0%
     complete  : 0=0.0%, 4=100.0%, 8=0.0%, 16=0.0%, 32=0.0%, 64=0.1%, >=64=0.0%
     issued    : total=r=2654335/w=0/d=0, short=r=0/w=0/d=0, drop=r=0/w=0/d=0
     latency   : target=0, window=0, percentile=100.00%, depth=64

Run status group 0 (all jobs):
   READ: io=31121MB, aggrb=3111.9MB/s, minb=1021.2MB/s, maxb=1053.1MB/s, mint=10001msec, maxt=10001msec

Disk stats (read/write):
  nvme0n1: ios=7883218/0, merge=0/0, ticks=1730536/0, in_queue=1763060, util=99.52%
```

Comment: Why are you talking about the one-core benchmark result of 1516.7MB/s as a "guarantee" or "limit"?  The only thing that's really surprising is exceeding the manufacturer's performance number.  But are you sure no OS caching happening?  (I haven't used `fio`, so IDK if different settings could lead to cache hits).  Or maybe Intel's perf numbers are somewhat conservative, and every model is guaranteed to be able to achieve that number when new, but some are even faster.

Comment: You also didn't specify what CPU model or frequency (e.g. Haswell 2.4GHz?  Skylake 4GHz?  At least give us a Xeon E5-xxx v4 number or something), or which Intel SSD 750 you have (different capacity models have different rated and actual speeds).

Comment: thanks for answering.                                                                           cpu : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2650 v3 @ 2.3GHZ  ,                                ssd : Intel Solid State Drive 750 series, 400GB, 20nm Intel NAND Flash Memory MLC. NVMe PCIe 3.0*4 ADD-In card.                                          yes. I could invalidate the buffer/page cache parts of the files to be used prior to starting I/O when i made the fio file.

Comment: and i used O_DIRECT flag(non-buffered IO) to bypass the page cache and used linux native  asynchronous I/O request.

Comment: O_DIRECT should avoid any OS-level caching, even if multiple threads happen to be reading the same block.  IDK if the 750 has any internal cache.  (And BTW, you should [edit] those details into your question, so future readers see it right away instead of just buried in the comments.)

Comment: thanks for answering. i heard about 'pre-conditioning'(same as pre-warming) just a few days ago. I wrote 50% of ssd capacity with sequential wirte before benchmarking. After that, i saw it works very well. I wrote 50% because i had to avoid GC. thansk a lot.                      Internal cache can be a problem. but 3000MB/s is too big to explain that. but it helps me understanding ssd internal mechanism. thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmm...

@peter-cordes makes a good point about (device) cache. Doing a Google search returns https://www.techspot.com/review/984-intel-ssd-750-series/ which says the following:

> Also onboard are five Micron D9PQL DRAM chips which are used as a 1.25GB cache and the specs say this is DDR3-1600 memory.

Given that you're restricting fio to working in the same 256MByte region for all threads it could well be all your I/O easily fits into the device's cache. There's no dedicated way of discarding a **device's** cache (as opposed to Linux's buffer cache) other than natural means though so I'd recommending making your working region dramatically bigger (e.g. 10s - 100s gigabytes) to reduce the odds of a thread's data being prefetched by another thread's accesses.

Additionally I would ask "what data did you put down on to the SSD before you read it back"? SSDs are typically "thin" in the sense they can be aware of regions that have never been written or where it has been told that a region has been explicitly discarded. Because of this reading from such regions means the SSD has little work to do and can return data extremely quickly (like what an OS does when you read from a hole in a sparse file). In "real life" it is rare that you choose to read something that you've never written, so doing such a thing will distort your results.

Comment: thanks for answering. i heard about 'pre-conditioning'(same as pre-warming) just a few days ago. I wrote 50% of ssd capacity with sequential wirte before benchmarking. After that, i saw it works very well. I wrote 50% because i had to avoid GC. thansk a lot.